# Execution of Symbian DLLs with no entry point

Tags: assembly, dll, arm, symbian, s60

My goal is creating an emulator for the pre-Symbian OS 9 based mobile gaming device called N-Gage. Sadly the execution of the device's (Symbian's) executables seems to be more complicated than I thought.

First, some background information. The device is based on the ARM920T processor, which is based on the ARMv4T architecture. The games made for the system are provided as DLLs, which are in the standard pre-Symbian 9 .app format. The SDK for the N-Gage is based off the Symbian S60 SDK 1st edition.

While some games execute some other miscellaneous instructions before, I'd first like to take a look at the first 3 "standard" instructions of every executable, which seem to have always been generated:

```
7C: B 0x1234 // The location of the branch can be anywhere
...
1234: MOV R0, #0
1238: BX LR
```

All of the DLLs also have 2 exports: the main entry (showcased above) and another export at a random point in the code.

The first couple instructions and the other circumstances of it have lead me to confusion:

1. Why would the game be a DLL instead of an actual executable?
2. How would the given DLL be loaded for execution by the system?
3. What would be the actual entry point of the DLL, if it has only the 2 exports mentioned above?
4. What would be the value of LR upon execution, assuming that the main entry point is called?

Comment: "Developing Software of Symbian OS" claims that prior to Symbian 9 it was common practice to have applications as DLL files, which would be loaded by the system application `apprun.exe`.

Comment: If the second export doesn't have a common name, then my guess is  that name would be specified as the game's entry point somewhere else, like in a database of installed applications. The value in LR is presumably the return address of function that called the main entry, which would normally be OS itself if it's the DLL's entry point. I'm guessing the entry point works like Windows' DLLMain and so often doesn't need to do anything. (Although a Windows DLL would return TRUE, not 0 (FALSE)).

Comment: Michael and Ross, thank you very much! You have led me to the right path. I've figured out the answer and posted an answer myself, that answers my own points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Michael, the application is instead compiled as a DLL and is then executed by apprun.exe. This clue has led me to the right path.

Going to answer my own points now:

> Why would the game be a DLL instead of an actual executable?

Seems like it's simply a weirdness of the Symbian OS.

> How would the given DLL be loaded for execution by the system?

First the E32Dll() initializer (the main "entry point") would be called and after that the NewApplication() function will be called, which should be the first exported function.

Most applications simply return false (0) from the E32Dll() to indicate success, but some applications do other processing before returning.

> What would be the actual entry point of the DLL, if it has only the 2 exports mentioned above?

The NewApplication() is the "real" entry point, though some applications do more processing in the E32Dll().

> What would be the value of LR upon execution, assuming that the main entry point is called?

The place where the E32Dll() was called from the apprun.exe.